How do I stop YouTube from giving me recommendations based on my conversations?
It has happened several times that I am just having a regular conversation with my friends or talking about something that I have never searched online, and then soon after, I get recommendations from YouTube about exactly those topics I talked about. At first, I thought it was a coincidence, but after this consistently happening again and again, I looked it up and found that I was not the only one with this experience.
When looking up how to turn it off, all I found was that I need to go to settings and turn off the access to the microphone for certain apps or disable Siri or other voice AIs. However, I already had turned off my microphone access for all apps in settings (except the phone one) and disabled Siri. In addition, I don’t even have YouTube downloaded as an app but just use the web instead and still have this problem. All the recommendations from above were essentially useless.
So how do I stop YouTube from listening to my conversations, giving me recommendations based upon those conversations, and committing what feels like a privacy breach? (There are probably more apps that are listening, but YouTube is where I have noticed it.)

Related article from YouTube Help Center -> Manage your recommendations & search results
